# New extra hard drive, not being detected by anything

Tags: hard-drive

Ok so I got a hard drive that I got from a person who said that they aren't using it because they got windows 10. I was like, Ok so I tried to clean all data of it. It wasn't being detected by ubuntu, so when I loaded it seperatly, it showed a windows 8.1 error loading page. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: When you plug it in does any fresh input show in `dmesg` and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 0):

First disconnect the harddrive, then go to the terminal and execute:`sudo fdisk -l` now connect your harddrive and again execute:`sudo fdisk -l`. Compare the output of both commands. You'll notice the second attempt produces a little more output and this is your hard drive. Then you can mount it using the mount command like:`mount /dev/sdx /media/mount`. /dev/sdx is the station designation you figured out using the commands above and /media/mount is the mount point you've to create first where you want fo connect your harddrive to in order to be able to access it.